# Need suggestion on my approach : to read a file which is being written continuously?

Tags: java, file, io

I have one csv file, which is being written continuously by script. It writes timestamp and some other data per row. I have to read the latest data first.
Currently I am using RandomAccessFile in java to read the file in reverse way. But as its written continuously, I have to read the new data with priority.  I am maintaining which timestamp has been sent and doing the work. It results unnecessary scanning operations.

Is there any better way to deal with this scenario?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider having one thread that reads new lines as they appear and pushes them onto a stack of unprocessed rows, and a second thread that pops the stack and processes the new rows in reverse order.

Depending on how long it takes to process a new row compared to how quickly they are generated, this might be sufficient. If new rows are generated faster than you can process them then this approach probably won't work - the stack will get too big and you'll run out of memory. In that case, depending on your requirements, you might be able to get away with a size-limited stack that discards old entries.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1. Use a fixed size record format instead of CSV. Then you can tell exactly what offsets your records are at instead of having to seek around looking for newlines.
2. If that isn't possible, have a thread that reads items from the file and pushes them onto a stack. Another thread pops items from the stack and processes them. Because it's a stack it'll always be dealing with the most recent available item. You'll need to figure out how you want to deal with cases where the stack gets too big. Do you just want to throw away items that are too old?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the original script, write the record to a database, in addition to the CSV file.  Then you can do whatever you want with the database; access the last record, run a report, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> It results unnecessary scanning operations.

I presume that you are referring to the overheads of seeking to some point, and then finding the next valid CSV row start position by reading until you hit the next newline.

I can think of three ways to do this that may be more efficient than what you are currently doing:

1. Read the entire file and parse out the rows in forwards direction, storing the positions in memory.  Then process the in-memory rows in reverse order.
2. Scan the file from the beginning looking for row starts, and store the row start positions in memory.  Then iterate through the positions in reverse order, seeking to each one to read the corresponding row.  (You can do the input more efficiently by processing multiple rows in each seek.)
3. Map the file into memory using a [`MappedByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html), then you can step through the Byte buffer forwards or backwards to find the row boundaries.

The first approach requires that you can buffer the entire file in memory, but has the lower I/O overheads because you read the file just once with a minimum number of system calls.  The third approach has the same the same issue, though you could map an extremely large file into memory in (large) sections to reduce the memory requirements.

But ultimately, there is no simple and efficient way of reading a file backwards in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is running in a Unix environment, you could run

```
tail -f /csv-file | custom-program
```

custom-program would simply accept standard input and echo that to a socket connection with your Java program.

I'm assuming that your Java program is some sort of server app that can't be started from the command line like that.  If that would actually be okay, then you could replace custom-program with your Java program.